# how to communicate with server with afnetworking?

Tags: ios

I am using `AFNetworking` Please take a look at my code

```
+(void)requestLogin:(id<LoginRequestDelegate>) delegate LoginURL:(NSString *)loginurl{

static User *user;
static id <LoginRequestDelegate> del;
del=delegate;
static AFHTTPRequestOperation *afRequest;
if(afRequest){
    return;
}
isLogin = NO;
Reachability *objInternetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus status = [objInternetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
if(status != NotReachable) {
    NSString *strUrl=loginurl;
    NSLog(@"Login JSON URL %@", strUrl);
    strUrl=[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURLRequest *urlReq=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    afRequest=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlReq];
    AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager * newactivity = [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager alloc] init];
    newactivity.enabled = YES;
    [afRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        newactivity.enabled = NO;
        NSString *strRes=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        //JSON DATA
        NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
        dic=[parser objectWithString:strRes];
        NSLog(@"Dic :- %@", dic);

        if(dic){
            NSString *isLoginRes = [dic objectForKey:@"login"];
            if([isLoginRes isEqualToString:@"true"]){
                NSLog(@"login res %@",isLoginRes);
                isLogin = YES;
                NSDictionary *resp = [dic objectForKey:@"resp"];
                user = [User sharedInstance];
                // User
                NSDictionary *userDic = [resp objectForKey:@"User"];
                user.userId = [userDic objectForKey:@"id"];
                user.userEmail = [userDic objectForKey:@"email"];
```

I am using this piece of code, but when i reach on this method it jump to failure block.

```
[afRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

This block is not executed.

The program moves jump on this block

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        newactivity.enabled = NO;
        if(del){
            [del isLoginRespomce:isLogin LoginDetail:user];
        }
```

Comment: Is the URL that you're requesting available and working? Giving back proper JSON etc?

Comment: thanks for your response, URL is working fine sir, it gives true when i hit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be much simpler, use for the AFNetworking stuff the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, it's really easy to use and works just as good as allocating your own `AFHTTPRequestOperation` etc.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:loginurl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: when i check my code line by line in log, so when i reached at this line "[afRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)"{ } than this block is not executed it jumps to failure and failure block also not executed it starts again from the button click

Comment: Have you tried it with the code i provided? This seems like you are still using your old code.

Comment: Nice! Good to hear it's working. Please accept this answer as valid by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer ;)